# MVC3 View controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Hey I need to connect my form to the controller how do I do in Spring MVC?

```
<form method="get"   action="customer">
                 <input type="text" value="default" /> <input type="submit" value="search"/> 
                 </form>
```

this is my controller

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderManagementController.class);

@Autowired
private OMPCamundaBridge ompCamundaBridge;

@RequestMapping( value="/customerlist",method= RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView dummylist()
{
    return new ModelAndView ()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need **modelAttribute** attribute for the binding to work.
See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-form-tutorial.html